# Applying delimiters to a list of bytes in serial protocol, replacing one byte with two

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, arrays

I am working on a serial commnuication protocol. In this protocol, the packt consists of bytes, and it should start and end with `0x7E`.

The protocol indicates that any byte which is `0x7E` or `0x7D` should be escaped to `0x7D 0x5E` or `0x7d 0x5D` accordingly.

Here is a sample packet:

```
7E 40 09 00 BE EF 05 7E 06 01 02 03 04 05 7E
```

As you can see, `byte[7]` in this packet should be replaced by 2 bytes `0x7D 0x5E`. To this I wrote the method below but it fails to do this task:

```
private List<byte> Finalize(List<byte> packet)
{
    int u = 1; //keep track of end of pack
    //because if escape characters are present
    //end bit will be shifted to right

    //Walk through list and fix escape bytes
    for (int i = 1; i < packet.Count; i++)
    {
        if (packet[i] == 0x7D)
        {
            packet[u] = 0x7D;
            packet[u + 1] = 0x5D;
            u += 2;
        }
        else if (packet[i] == 0x7E) //Sync Byte
        {
            packet[u] = 0x7D;
            packet[u + 1] = 0x5E;
            u += 2;
        }
        else
        {
           packet[u] = packet[i]; //Exception here!!
           u++;
        }
    }

    return packet;
}
```

The method throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Can someone tell me what can be the problem!? I guess I implemented a correct logic but it seems I didn't handle indexes properly!

The loop is starting at index 1, because its the start byte and it shouldnt be changed. it also shouldn't change the last byte in the list which is 0x7E, the end byte!

Comment: You are indexing the List beyond the Count.  There's little point to do it this way, do this when you send the packet.  Just call SerialPort.WriteByte(), twice is you need to escape it.  Perf is a complete non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are loosing the data when you overwrite your byte next to bytes with values  `0x7D` and `0x7E`. Second, you are changing `u` faster than `i` which produces the Exception mentioned. When you escape your bytes, you add 2 to `u` but in that iteration of the `for` loop, i is only incremented. Third, the better approach for this would definitely be while loop.

To handle the first problem you should add more elements to the list. `Insert` would do the trick instead of shifting everything manually to the right. The second problem you can solve by using only one counter. Check the code:

```
        private List<byte> Finalize(List<byte> packet)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (i < packet.Count-1)
            {
                if (packet[i] == 0x7D)
                {
                    packet[i] = 0x7D;
                    packet.Insert(i+1, 0x5D);
                    i += 2;
                }
                else if (packet[i] == 0x7E) //Sync Byte
                {
                    packet[i] = 0x7D;
                    packet.Insert(i+1, 0x5E);
                    i += 2;
                }
                else 
                    i++;
            }
            return packet;
       }
```

The other solution would be creating new list within the method and adding appropriate values to it.
 `while (i < packet.Count-1)` is because I think that you don't want to escape the ending byte. Have in mind that the last byte in your list is `packet[packet.Count-1]` not `packet[packet.Count]`

Comment: Thanks this work great :P just add the i++ after the `else if` block

Comment: @Saeid87 Yes I missed that, sorry, it was in a hurry. I'm a little bit slow for this place :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a new list, and copying data from the original list to the new one.  While there may be ways of doing the update "in-place", it's probably easier to simply create a new list.  Actually, using a `byte[]` rather than `List<byte>` might be better, though you'd have to count the number of 7D or 7E characters in the original array before creating the new one.

Comment: Well yeah but I am allso have to take care of performance, I am a noob but I think making new arrays/lists can have a performance hit if the application needs to send packets say in 1ms or less intervals

Comment: That should take far less than 1 ms anyway, but if you're too concerned about performance then why are you even doing an O(n) operation before sending the packet? Why not escape the bytes as you send them?

Comment: @JeffE: Sending the packets is going to be O(n) whether one does the processing before or after.  If the data starts out in a list, creating a new array, copying the data there (with escapes), and then sending the array using a single API call is unlikely to be any worse than (and would likely be better than) trying to send out characters one at a time from a `List<byte>`, even if one processes the escapes while transmitting.

Comment: @Saeid87: The performance of `List<byte>` isn't horrible, but arrays are very fast--so much so that unless your packets are really huge (over 64K), creating a new array for each packet is likely to be faster than using a `List<byte>`, even if you only create a `List<byte>` once and keep re-using it.

Comment: Saeid87 - You're assuming that Insert doesn't allocate memory. In fact it may be slightly slower.  In the least I would expect it to do a malloc + memcpy.   A new array would likely be faster. However, unless the packets are really large and there are multiple insertions I think you won't notice any difference.

Comment: @Matt: I would expect an insert to perform a new allocation if and only if it would cause the list to be larger than its allocated space (in which case the allocated space will be increased to either twice the old value, or the required new value, whichever is larger).  Of greater significance is the subroutine-call overhead required for every subscripting operation on a `List<byte>`; subscripting an array, by contrast, uses special dedicated instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method, which escapes packet. It does not touch first and last bytes, which are default.

```
public static IEnumerable<byte> Finalize(this IList<byte> packet)
{
    yield return 0x7E;

    for(int i = 1; i < packet.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (packet[i] == 0x7E)
        {
            yield return 0x7D;
            yield return 0x5E;
            continue;
        }

        if (packet[i] == 0x7D)
        {
            yield return 0x7D;
            yield return 0x5D;
            continue;
        }

        yield return packet[i];
    }

    yield return 0x7E;
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
byte[] packet = { 0x7E, 0x40, 0x09, 0xEF, 0x05, 0x7E, 0x06, 0x04, 0x05, 0x7E };
byte[] escapedPacket = packet.Finalize().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with c#, but it looks like you're overwriting the source packet, corrupting it as you go.

Also, does List grow automatically? because you're writing beyond it's length.  How does List handle that?

Should the loop start from 1 or 0? because your exit condition is "i < packet.Count" not "i <= packet.Count" which would miss the last byte.

Comment: I guess it should grow, because I escapte those bytes with 2 bytes. The loop is starting at index 1, because its the start byte and it shouldnt be changed. it also shouldn't change the last byte in the list which is 0x7E, the end byte!

Comment: Yes you should have used Insert.